# SQL Split multiple groups of columns into rows from a view

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

I'm working on a legacy view which for a key returns multiple subsets of data that I would like as separate rows. Example of what's being returned:

```
|a  |b  |cStartQty |cUpdatedQty |dStartQty |dUpdatedQty |
|1  |2  |10        |20          |15        |20          |
|2  |4  |11        |18          |16        |21          |
```

What I'd like returned is something like

```
|a  |b  |Account   |StartQty |UpdatedQty |
|1  |2  |cXX       |10       |20         |
|1  |2  |dXX       |15       |21         |
|2  |4  |cXX       |11       |18         |
|2  |4  |dXX       |16       |21         |
```

At first I thought I could do this with a chain of unions but that would require many redundant queries on the view (there are approximately 15 subsets). Outside of that I don't really have a clue how to proceed. If necessary I thought I may have to wrap this view in a proc and go that route.

Comment: Are you specifically tied to using the view? Can  you paste the SQL the view is using it could be easier just to re-write the joins/groupings?

Answer (score 0):

You ca use UNNEST:

```
SELECT 
 a, 
 b, 
 UNNEST(ARRAY[cStartQty, dStartQty]) as StartQty, 
 UNNEST(ARRAY[cUpdateQty, dUpdateQty]) as UpdateQty
FROM mytable
```

** UPDATE **

Sorry, I didn't notice you are using sybase. 
I don't know if sybase supports unnest, but I will leave the answer as it is to see if someone can confirm sybase support. The proposed query works on Postgresql.

Comment: This seems like it will work for a set number of quantity columns, but from the OP's wording it sounds like the number of columns will vary.

Comment: Hi @PatJones, There is no way the column subsets are magically defined. He have to define which columns define each subset.